# 'System.InvalidOperationException' error when trying to save a specific Excel file

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I am using the following code to access an Excel file and read from it, but keep getting a System.InvalidOperationException saying an error occurred:

```
   using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(source)))
        {
            foreach (ExcelWorksheet sheet in package.Workbook.Worksheets)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Parse(sheet);
            }
            package.Save();
        }

        GC.Collect();
```

and this is the method parse:

```
        private void Parse(ExcelWorksheet Sheet)
    {
        String name = Sheet.Name;

        using (ExcelWorksheet sheet = Sheet)
        {

            if (name.Equals(SUMMARRY_SHEET))
            {
                int col = get_col(sheet);
                this.parse_summary(sheet,col);
                Console.WriteLine("successful summary sheet parsing - " + DbName);
            }
        }

    }
```

(Dbname, SUMMARY_SHEET are strings)
parse_summarry() is just a method that read one of the sheets in the files.

This happens with only one of the files I am using, and the same one each time. If I remove the save command the program works fine except that the file doesn't close properly and then the next run of the program will fail (an exception is thrown) since the file is still open and in use.

Comment: Could it be the `Parse` function?  Does the problem go away if take it out?  How many files have you tried it on?

Comment: maybe it's Parse, but it only happens with one file, i'm using this code with another one too and it doesn't happen.

Comment: Post what parse is doing. Otherwise people can l only guess what is going on.

Comment: @Ernie I've edited my post. but this program is a bit long and also i'm not sure how much i'm allowed to share (it's work stuff). the rest is just accessing the Value property of cells in the sheet.